# Defining MIB for array type of field

Tags: snmp, mib

I'm trying to define an MIB for the following sample MO:

```
tabular_mo_struct
{
    int index1;
    int index2;
    int address [10];
    int flag;
}
```

flag above can take values like this (bitmask type):

val1,
val2,
val3,

or a combination of above val1 | val2 | ...

I'm a bit unclear

- if my MIB should represent "address" as an octet string? I could not find any other suitable type.
- What is the best way to represent "flag" in MIB?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of "address"? Street address, MAC address, IPv4, IPv6? You'll find that all but one of those have a specifically defined "syntax" in SNMP.

Comment: Thanks. address in my MO is of integer type. one row in the MO indexed by index1,index2 may thus have 10 addresses (as defined in the above structure).

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't follow what the "address" signifies. I can't come up with any type of address that's made up of ten integers. A MAC address is 6 bytes, an IPv4 address is 4 bytes, an IPv6 address is 128 bits, etc.
If it is just another word for "sequence of integers", then yes, you should probably make up a TEXTUAL-CONVENTION describing them as OCTET STRING, with DISPLAY-HINT like "1d 1d 1d 1d 1d 1d 1d 1d 1d 1d" or similar.

Comment: Yes, it is a the "sequence of integers" I was referring to and was not sure if any current type and TC can be used. As I understood, a new TC would be required to achieve this. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the address field, you probably need to define a table.

For the flag, you can use `BITS`, which is a derived type from `OCTET STRING`,

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578#page-22

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the above structure is a tabular object for me and a specific row in that table will have a field named "address" (sequence of 10 integers). As I understood from the previous comment, this can be achieved by defining a new TC, since existing TCs will not fit in this case.

Comment: Also, as per the definition of BITs "This
   collection is assigned non-negative, contiguous (but see below)
   values, starting at zero". Can I use it, even if sometimes this variable takes value which is OR-ed combination of these named bits?

Comment: If tabular_mo_struct is already a row in a table, then you need to define a second table to hold address. Similar cases can be found from standard RFCs such as TCP and UDP MIB documents. For your BITS question, I couldn't see why you cannot.